# Backbone.js - custom setters

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Imagine a simple backbone model like

```
window.model= Backbone.Model.extend({
   defaults:{
      name: "",
      date: new Date().valueOf()
   }
})
```

I'm trying to find a way to always make the model store the name in lower-case irrespective of input provided. i.e.,

```
model.set({name: "AbCd"})
model.get("name") // prints "AbCd" = current behavior
model.get("name") // print "abcd" = required behavior
```

What's the best way of doing this? Here's all I could think of:

1. Override the "set" method
2. Use a "SantizedModel" which listens for changes on this base model and stores the sanitized inputs. All view code would then be passed this sanitized model instead.

The specific "to lower case" example I mentioned may technically be better handled by the view while retrieving it, but imagine a different case where, say, user enters values in Pounds and I only want to store values in $s in my database. There may also be different views for the same model and I don't want to have to do a "toLowerCase" everywhere its being used.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATE**: you can use the plug-in: https://github.com/berzniz/backbone.getters.setters

---

You can override the set method like this (add it to your models):

```
set: function(key, value, options) {
    // Normalize the key-value into an object
    if (_.isObject(key) || key == null) {
        attrs = key;
        options = value;
    } else {
        attrs = {};
        attrs[key] = value;
    }

    // Go over all the set attributes and make your changes
    for (attr in attrs) {
        if (attr == 'name') {
            attrs['name'] = attrs['name'].toLowerCase();
        }
    }

    return Backbone.Model.prototype.set.call(this, attrs, options);
}
```

Comment: instead of a loop i would recommend if(attrs.name)attrs.name = attrs.name.toLowerCase();

Comment: Note that if the first paramter is an object, setting of the attributes is delegated to `set` with a string as the first parameter. So normalization is only needed if the first parameter is a string.

Answer (score 5):

It would be a hack, because this isn't what it was made for, but you could always use a validator for this:

```
window.model= Backbone.Model.extend({
   validate: function(attrs) {
      if(attrs.name) {
         attrs.name = attrs.name.toLowerCase()
      }

      return true;
   }
})
```

The validate function will get called (as long as the `silent` option isn't set) before the value is set in the model, so it gives you a chance to mutate the data before it gets really set.

Comment: Thanks. I considered this too, but this seemed to be step backward in terms of making it readable - overriding the set function or adding a new "setProperty" function which sets it in lowercase and then passes it into backbone set might be better. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: There's certainly nothing wrong with overriding the `set` method to get done what you need to get done... some pre-processing before the set?  You might even consider extending `Backbone.Model.prototype.set` to call some pre-processors if they match... something like this: https://gist.github.com/1310972

Comment: validate is only called for the save method or if options.validate = true is set. (silent is not used here, but the answer is quite old)

Answer (score 3):

Not to toot my own horn, but [I created a Backbone model](https://github.com/narenranjit/backbone-misc) with "Computed" properties to get around this. In other words

```
var bm = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
     fullName: function(){return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName},
     lowerCaseName: function(){
        //Should probably belong in the view
        return this.firstName.toLowerCase();  

     }
   }
})
```

You also listen for changes on computed properties and pretty much just treat this as a regular one.

[The plugin Bereznitskey mentioned](https://github.com/berzniz/backbone.getters.setters) is also a valid approach.

Comment: I'm trying this now and it is echoing my actual function rather that the return value. `defaults: { distance: function() { return 10; }
  },` then `console.log(this.model.get('distance'));` ??

Comment: @trapper - are you extending from the "BasecomputedModel" from the linked github?