# preprocessing models in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, preprocessor

What is a good way to do some preprocessing on fields of a model. For example, suppose I have this data:

```
[{
        id: '1',
        sender: 'me',
        receiver: 'you',
        message: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum",
        date: new Date("October 13, 1975 11:13:00").toLocaleDateString()
    }]
```

In this simple model:

```
App.Models.Notification = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        'date': new Date()
    }
});
```

And I want to reduce the number of characters in the value of `message` in order to display it in a view, but only if that message contains more than a given number of characters. Maybe something like this:

```
if ( this.model.get('message').trim().split(" ").length > 30 ) {
  // code here
}
```

So, I don't want to perform that preprocessing in all models. Should I do it in my view? If so, how?  I have [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842378/backbone-js-custom-setters) a few solutions but some of them don't apply to this situation and others seem like a hack.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Following Alex's suggestion and as a reference, I put here an example of using Handlebars' template helpers:

```
render: function() {

    Handlebars.registerHelper('getShort', function(options) {
        if ( options.fn(this).trim().split(" ").length > 30 ) {
            var message = options.fn(this);
            var shortText = $('<div/>', { text: message })
            .html()
            .trim()
            .substring(0, 200)
            .split(" ")
            .slice(0, -1)
            .join(" ") + "..."

            return shortText;
        }
        return options.fn(this);
    });

    template = Handlebars.compile( $("#my-template").html() );
    this.$el.html( template( this.model.toJSON() ));
    return this;
}
```

and using it like this:

#### index.html

```
{{#getShort}}{{message}}{{/getShort}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of presentation logic should be put in template helpers, if your library stack supports them.  If not, just add `getShortenedMessage(length)` method to model and use it to get your value.  In any case, don't change actual model attribute just to display it differently -- this is bad design and can lead to all kinds of complications later.

Comment: Exactly. I don't want to change the model because it could lead to unwanted behavior when saving it, however, I can't really add getShortenedMessage to the models because that would affect every collection relying on those models, right? As I stated, I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Have you considered adding this method to some class like `MyModel` and extending it instead of vanilla `Backbone.Model`?

Comment: +1 for using (or creating) a template helper. If you're strictly looking to shorten the message field for presentation, it probably belongs at the presentation layer.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by extending MyModel. Do you mean using javascript prototyping instead of Backbone's extend? By the way, template helpers look nice. I'm using underscore, so I guess that's not good enough. Maybe using handlebars?

Answer (score 1):

It is best practice to put that kind of logic into an external helper function, and then pass the results into your template.

For example, if you had something like this:

```
var NotificationHelper = {
    trimmedMessage: function (notification, limit) {
        // do trimming logic here based on notification.get('message')
        return value;
    }
    ... // other helper functions
};
```

And given a template like this:

```
template: _.template('<p><%- message %></p><p><%= foo %></p>'),
```

Then in your view code you can do something like this:

```
this.$el.html( this.template({
    message: NotificationHelper.trimmedMessage(this.model),
    foo: this.model.get('foo')
});
```

I'll tend to get view helpers that have several functions in them. It helps keep the presentation logic out of your models. By passing the calculated values into your templates, it will keep your templates much more readable and manageable.

Also, things like truncating text can be put in a non model specific helper, since it is pretty generic type of functionality.

Comment: I like this. It's a bit more work than using Handlebars' template helpers but this is a very good option. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `underscore.string` library ([Link](http://epeli.github.com/underscore.string))

Basically, you can simply call the function truncate/prune ([Link](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string#readme)) in the render function, which will return you the shortened version..

```
render: function() {
     var shortenedMessage = _('Hello, world').prune(8); // => 'Hello...'
}
```

If the message length is not above the amount of characters, it just returns the string back.
Note that you can also use it with `Underscore.js`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally it's best to have a function in the model. That way it can be reused by anyone else who uses that model. The template can call the function and it will only get processed at the moment you need it.

```
App.Models.Notification = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        get shortdate() {
            // put the code here to return the custom date format
        }
    }
});

// in the template (or anywhere else)
<div id='date'><%= Notification.shortdate %></div>
```

For bonus points use a custom getter (supported in IE9+). So it looks like a property but only processes the function when it's called. Since there is no setter it can't be set.

Answer (score 0):

Create a model constructor and then shorten the string if it is too long before you set it inside the constructor. See this [page](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor) for more info about `Model` constructor.

Comment: But that would modify every collection using those models, right? As I said before, I want to avoid that.