# listening every time a model attribute sets

Tags: backbone.js

I have a backbone model like -

```
ModelA = Backbone.Model.extend({
   this.set("prop1",true);
})
```

and View like -

```
ViewA = Backbone.View.extend({
      initialize : function(){
           this.listenTo(this.model,"change:prop1",this.changeProp1)l;
           this.model.set("prop1",true);
      },
      changeProp1 : function(){
          // callback doesn't call because I'm setting the same value
      }

});

var model1 = new ModelA();
var view1 = new ViewA({model:model1});
```

Here the callback changeProp1 triggers whenever prop1 changes from *true -> false -> true* .
But **I want to listen everytime whenever I'm setting the same value or different value**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backbone.js - custom setters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842378/backbone-js-custom-setters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it's best to leave the `change` event alone, and implement a new `set` event (or whatever you want to call it).  After all, you want to be notified about things that aren't strictly 'changes'.

You could implement your own version of `set()` in your model which fires a custom 'set' event and then calls backbone's usual set method afterwards.

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    set: function(key, val, options) {
        // Deal with single name/value or object being passed in
        var changes;
        if (typeof key === 'object') {
          changes = key;
          options = val;
        } else {
          (changes = {})[key] = val;
        }

        options || (options = {});

        // Trigger 'set' event on each property passed in
        for (var i = 0, l = changes.length; i < l; i++) {
            this.trigger('set:' + changes[i], this, this.attributes[changes[i]], options);
        }

        // Call the usual backbone 'set' method
        Backbone.Model.prototype.set.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

and then listen for your new event instead of (or as well as) 'change', where appropriate:

```
ViewA = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize : function(){
       this.listenTo(this.model,"set:prop1",this.changeProp1)l;
       this.model.set("prop1",true);
  },
```

However, most of this code is just lifted from Backbone's default `set` method, and doesn't deal with some other issues such as some option flags and nested events.  If you wanted to change the Backbone source itself, the line you want to look for is:

```
if (!_.isEqual(current[attr], val)) changes.push(attr);
```

(line 347 in version 1.0.0) and try removing that `if` clause.

(Code above isn't tested, sorry for any syntax errors)

Comment: I tried to override set method using your code .It didn't work

Answer (score 0):

For implementing above , you have to make changes in change function in backbone.js . Change checks whether the value of the property changed if yes than only it calls the binded function.

Comment: how to override Backbone's change event?